# How much energy would be required to increase the velocity of an electron from 0 to 0.9c?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, velocity

I looked it up on the web and found a few different equations such as

- E = ymc^2
- K.E = 0.5mv^2
- E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2 where p = ymv

From my what I know, the closer an object gets to the speed of light, the more energy it has and the more heavier it becomes. The 2nd equation doesn’t seem to deal with relativistic speeds so I’m unsure about that one. But the other two seem to be the energy possessed by the electron and not the energy I need to put into the electron to increase its speed.
When I inserted the values, I got really small numbers which I didn’t expect it but when I assumed the electron was going at the speed of light, they seem to work (they gave me infinity y= 1/0). So I was thinking if there is another equation that describes the energy needed to increase the electrons speed close to the speed of light.

Comment: I've always been taught that $1/0$ is *undefined*, not infinity.

Comment: Yes, but it seems it is just taken as infinity in physics (at least in some answers I read). I don’t know why though.

Comment: perhaps they were using $\lim_{x\to0}1/x=\infty$, but $1/0$ should be noted as undefined and, hence, unphysical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a little bit on *how* you add the energy, because an accelerating electron will radiate power (according to the [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) and this needs to be replenished.

What this means is that if you put your electron in a synchrotron, and slowly increase the energy, then it will lose a relatively large amount of energy; in a linear accelerator, the loss will be smaller.

If we ignore these losses, then the kinetic energy of the electron is given by

$$E = mc^2 - m_0 c^2 = (\gamma-1) m_0 c^2 = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\right)m_0 c^2$$

It's not hard to see that this reduces to $\frac12 mv^2$ when $v\ll c$. I will leave it up to you to substitute numbers.